# Return value using arrow syntax

Tags: javascript, closures, arrow-functions

So to my understanding which is obviously wrong at this moment in time is that,

```
return arg => arg*2
```

is the same as

```
return (arg)=>{arg*2}
```

I always assumed arrow functions are just syntactically neater.

But doing this with closures like so doesn't work.

```
function addTwoDigits(firstDigit){
    return (secondDigit)=>{firstDigit + secondDigit}
}
let closure = addTwoDigits(5);
console.log(closure(5)) // Undefined
```

Yet this is fine

```
function addTwoDigitsV2(firstDigit){
    return secondDigit => firstDigit + secondDigit
}
let closure2 = addTwoDigitsV2(10);
console.log(closure2(10))// 20
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I'll mark this question as answered when the time limit has subsided appreciate the help.

Comment: The word closure is a bit of red herring in this question as the problem doesn't have anything to do with closures, but is a syntax issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

arrow function works differently here:-

```
(x)=> x*2 ; // dont have to return anything, x*2 will be returned
is not same as 
(x) =>{x*2}
//here you need to return something otherwise undefined will be returned
```

Comment: Can't see the correct terminology here anywhere, so I thought I'd chuck in that the first example is an example of _implicit return_, which arrow functions support.

Answer (score 5):

When you use {} you must set return

```
return (arg)=>{return arg*2}
```

Answer (score 3):

The arrow function only supplies the `return` automatically if you have an expression after the arrow. If the arrow is followed by a curly brace, it's treated as the braces around a function body, so you have to write `return` explicitly, i.e.

```
arg => arg * 2
```

is equivalent to:

```
(arg) => { return arg * 2; }
```

```js
function addTwoDigits(firstDigit) {
  return (secondDigit) => {
    return firstDigit + secondDigit
  }
}
let closure = addTwoDigits(5);
console.log(closure(5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `return` statement if the body of your arrow function is wrapped in `{` ... `}`.

Since yours is a single expression, you can skip the `{`-`}` and `return`.  But if you have the `{`-`}`, you need the `return` statement.

The parentheses are not an issue here.  You need them if you have more than a single parameter.  With one, they're optional.

Comment: Thank you that clears things up, much appreciated.